# Does Wordpress has an automatic link parse function?

Tags: functions, parse

Does wordpress has an automatic link parse function? I want the HTML to be generated automatically when writing

```
www.url.com -> <a href="www.url.com">www.url.com</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [`make_clickable`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/make_clickable) which is applied as a filter on `comment_text` but not on post/page content. You could add it as a filter with...

```
add_filter('the_content','make_clickable');
```

Untested. I have not idea how well that will behave. There may or may not be conflicts with already defined URLs, or other markup. I haven't investigated that. Be aware.

Comment: Is it possible to do this after a page loads as I'm using shortcodes in my page.