# Can make_clickable work with shortcodes?

Tags: shortcode

I've looked at this... [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76394/does-wordpress-has-an-automatic-link-parse-function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76394/does-wordpress-has-an-automatic-link-parse-function#new-answer)

But because I'm using shortcodes in my page it doesn't work. Is there a way to make this work (may be after the page loads) with shortcodes?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/make_clickable/

Comment: Short answer: Yes. But, "*because I'm using shortcodes in my page it doesn't work*" - how are you using them? Did you create/code the shortcode on your own? Please add all the relevant code to your post.